# Magnitude of Average Velocity

Tags: physics, vectors, average

A train travels 100 miles toward 37 degrees northwest and then 90 miles north. The whole journey takes 2 hours. What is the magnitude of the average velocity of the train?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE ! People here are willing to help but, please, show your efforts. Explain what you already tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Hint : resolve the velocity components and then calculate average velocity of individual components

Comment: Ah, sorry. I drew some vectors like I normally would for this problem. For example, in the last problem I drew some vectors according to the information given and was able to construct a right triangle out of the vector diagram. After that it was obvious I needed to use Pythagoras' theorem. But this time it doesn't seem like you can construct a right triangle. I ended up with a very thin triangle, the resultant vector facing northwest, in the second quadrant. I thought maybe I could use the law of cosines, but I don't know how to find theta in this case. I'm very confused.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{(100\cos 37)^2+(100\sin 37+90)^2}}{2}\approx85.05$

1. The cosinus is the x/east component of the journey.
2. The sinus is the first part of the y/north component and is added to the second part of the jouney, that went straight to north.
3. The square root is Pythagoras theorem on the components of the distances $d=\sqrt{ x^2+y^2}$.
4. The divisor $2$ is the time and $\displaystyle v=\frac{d}{t}$.

Comment: Could you explain how you did this? I think I'm gonna cry.

Comment: I swear, I was trying to figure this out at this point by taking out a ruler and just trying to measure the length of the resultant arrow at this point... ;_;

Comment: Then I'm gonna cry! OK, I'll try.

Comment: Never mind, I quit. I will come back to this later. I am on the verge of tears. I am an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out after having a rest!

I constructed the vector diagram, discovered that I have two sides and an angle. From there I let delta(x) = sqrt[100^2 + 90^2 - 2(100)(90)cos(127)] = 170 mi. 
Average velocity = delta(x)/delta(t) = 170 mi/2 hr = 85 mi/hr.